# implications of a no soliciting sign / soliciting

Tags: word-usage

*Look Steve, there's a no soliciting sign so we can't go to that house to try to sell our goods.*

From what I know a no soliciting sign means that the owner doesn't want to deal with people who raise money, want to convert you to their faith etc. But is it also to deflect salespeople?

Also, are those people who solicit like JW witnesses, people raising funds (and salespeople if you confirm positively) called solicitors?

And, just to be safe, is there any difference between the nouns soliciting and solicitation?

Answer (score 1):

Sign: No soliciting

Means: do not come and try to sell your goods or services or hawk your wares (idiom) here.

Collins Dictionary
solicitor

NOUN

1. **a person who solicits; esp., one who seeks trade, asks for contributions, etc.** [BrE and AmE]
2. **in England**, a member of the legal profession who is not a barrister: solicitors are not members of the bar and may not plead cases in superior courts
3. US
   in the U.S., a lawyer serving as official law officer for a city, department, etc.

However, there are the two other meanings as listed above. Also, in the UK soliciting is also selling goods or services where  you are  not allowed to. A prostitute is said to solicit for sell her/his services.

Comment: Aged 9, I used to read the local weekly newspaper, the _South London Press_. It had a page of cases heard at the various magistrate's courts. One caught my eye. It contained our address! My parents owned the house and rented the downstairs flat to Mr & Mrs G----n. We lived in the top two floors. 'Dad!', I asked, 'What's "soliciting"?'. 'Why do you want to know?' he asked warily. 'Because Mrs G----n has been fined £10 for it at Camberwell Magistrates Court'. Dad: 'Give me that paper!' Mr G----n also got fined for drunk & disorderly that week. Soon after they stopped paying rent & were evicted.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Was she selling her bodily services?

Comment: That or renting them out. It was (and is) the usual police/court term for offering to perfom sexual services for money. It is still an offence for someone to 'solicit or loiter in a public place for the purposes of prostitution'. The teenage daughter annoyed my dad by carving 'I LOVE ELVIS' into the front of the house. That tells you how long ago it was. I later asked my dad what 'importuning' was because Wilfrid Brambell (Old Steptoe) had been fined for it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey We really should start using the chat for this type of thing.

Comment: Maybe, but the extra UK meaning of 'soliciting' might be useful, as its incorrect use could cause embarrassment or worse.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you or do you not have signs that say No Soliciting in the UK in and around business or apartment buildings?

Comment: You can buy them to fix on or near doors, for around £5.

Comment: @Lambie - I think 'No cold calling' is more common in the UK, because of the other senses of 'soliciting'.

Comment: @KateBunting No cold calling on a SIGN that you put up on your property. Really? Because that is ambiguous too.

Comment: @Lambie - plenty [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=no+cold+callers+sign+for+front+door+uk&crid=29XVACJIW5OMT&sprefix=no+cold+callers+sign+for+front+door+uk%2Caps%2C78&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) from £1.48